# getActivity() returns null - The second time I open the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

The `ShowActivities` fragment is being instantiated when I press a button. The first time I press it everything is working fine. This is what I get in logCat :

```
11-16 23:41:12.560 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreate: getActivity() == null: false
11-16 23:41:12.560 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreate: Hash: 1036405628
11-16 23:41:12.570 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreateView: getActivity() == null: false
11-16 23:41:12.570 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreateView: Hash: 1036405628
11-16 23:41:12.630 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onConnected: getActivity() == null: false
11-16 23:41:12.630 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onConnected: Hash: 1036405628
```

Everything is working fine. I press the back key and go back to the previous fragment. And now I click the button again to open `ShowActivities` fragment and now what logCat returns is:

```
11-16 23:41:13.890 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreate: getActivity() == null: false
11-16 23:41:13.890 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreate: Hash: 252302789
11-16 23:41:13.890 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreateView: getActivity() == null: false
11-16 23:41:13.890 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onCreateView: Hash: 252302789
11-16 23:41:13.900 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onConnected: getActivity() == null: true
11-16 23:41:13.900 25874-25874/name.company.newapp E/onConnected: Hash: 1036405628
```

`onConnected` is called on the same fragment, although onCreate is creating another.

ShowActivities fragment

```
    public class ShowActivities extends Fragment implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


        public ShowActivities() {
        }

        private static GoogleApiClient googleClient;
        private Location mLastLocation;
        private PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Log.e("onCreate"," "+(getActivity() == null));
            if (googleClient==null) {
                googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
Log.e("onCreateView"," "+(getActivity() == null));
            // Defines the xml file for the fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_activity_fragment, container, false);
            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.e("onConnected"," "+(getActivity() == null));
            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleClient, builder.build());

            if (result != null) {
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                                // requests here.

                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                                // a optionsDialog.
                                try {
                                    // Show the optionsDialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                    if (status.hasResolution()) {
                                        status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 1000);
                                        Log.e("location", "Resolution");
                                    }
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    // Ignore the error.
                                    Log.e("location", "Resolution2");
                                }
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                                // settings so we won't show the optionsDialog.
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if ((resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == 1000)) {
                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleClient);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e("location", "finally");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (googleClient!=null) {
                googleClient = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

This was solved. I modified onPause to make the googleClient null once I exit the fragment.

Comment: Why don't you initialize the fragment before execute the transaction?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem

Comment: is `FragmentActivities` a `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: A fragment. I have only one activity in the entire project.

Comment: Start with the exception stacktrace to learn where in the fragment lifecycle the problem is.

Comment: @laalto posted the logcat

Comment: The stacktrace shows an async request completing while the fragment is not attached to an activity. Nothing to do with your button clicks directly. Consider refactoring your async calls away from your fragments. Or just cancel the request when the fragment goes out of scope. Or at least check for fragment attached state when the request completes.

Comment: The async starts when the fragment is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the Fragment instance in the placeholder by TAG first, it there is no previous intance, then create an instance.

```
    Fragment ShowActivities = getFragmentManager().getFragmentByTag(YOUR_TAG);
    if (showActivities == null) {
        showActivities = new ShowActivities();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.your_placeholder, showActivities, YOUR_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

Comment: there is always something in the placeholder. I use the same placeholder for all fragments

Comment: Then you can user a  Tag in the replace method to identify this instance.

Comment: Ok, I will try to modify it now, but how is this going to solve the problem  ?

Comment: I was suspecting that you were calling a method of a Fragment instance that's not actually added to the Activity. If this trick doesn't work, you will have to paste your code of your Fragment.

Comment: Sorry there is not enough information to tell what's wrong, have to have a look at the code of the Fragment.

Comment: Uploaded the fragment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change the super method call in onCreateView to call super.onCreateView(...) please.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_activity_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Then move this piece to onActivityCreated(...)

```
client = new NightAssetRestClient(getActivity());
    locationQueries = new LocationQueries(getActivity());
    if (googleClient==null) {
        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
```

Still, you need to check null in onConnect(...) anyway because the Async process could hold the reference of this Fragment even when the underlying Activity is destroyed.

Adding the line `setRetainInstance(boolean)` in the onCreate method may help.

Comment: Change it. Sorry. I usually have nothing there in the other fragments. I added it because I thought it might solve the problem. I modified it now to `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

Comment: The problem was not there anyway. I have no idea how this is happening.

Comment: getActivity(..) is not guaranteed to return a value anyway. My edited answer may help alleviate the problem.

Comment: This is not ok man.. so if you check for the getActivity() in `onCreate` is true, but if you check in `onConnected` is false. How does this happen ?

Comment: Fragments and Activities have different life-cycles, they are not synced. One instance of Fragment can be kept even after the Activity is destroyed and re-created. It's normal that getActivity() returns null.

Comment: What I'm saying is that in the same instance of the fragment(if you tried it in android studio) onCreate - true , onViewCreate - true, onConnected -false. I still think that there is something else happening.

Comment: Could you print out the  hashCode() of the Fragment instance to see if it is indeed the same instance plz.

Comment: Put this in your Fragment's lifecycle methods Log.e("onConnected"," "+ this.hasHashCode());

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I updated the question now. It makes it more clear. How can this be solved now ? The onConnected method is called on the previous fragment, but onCreate on a new one

Comment: Forcing the Android OS to keep the same instance of the Fragment is a hacky way. My suggestion is to move the code to call Google API into the Activity and use callbacks to communicate with the Fragment.

Comment: Solved it. I just modified onPause.